# Extracing a Stream from ImagePart

Tags: c#, xml, openxml, openxml-sdk

I have a `w:pict/Picture` within a run, to which I am trying to get the `Stream` of, to copy it to another part of the document.

I've taken the relationship (`Id = r1`), and loaded the part from the `MainDocumentPart`, to be given a `CustomXmlPart` (which doesn't seem right, but the XML suggests it is)... but upon checking my Relationships.xml, the part Id links to bibliography not image data....

Thoughts?

```
internal static Run CreateImageFromPicObj(WordprocessingDocument sourceDoc, Run sourceRun, OpenXmlPart headerFooterPart, Picture pic)
{
    ImageData data = pic.Descendants<ImageData>().FirstOrDefault();

    OpenXmlPart customP = sourceDoc.MainDocumentPart.GetPartById(data.RelationshipId);

    return CreateCustomImageRun(sourceDoc, sourceRun, headerFooterPart, customP, pic);        
}

private static Run CreateCustomImageRun(WordprocessingDocument sourceDoc, Run sourceRun, OpenXmlPart headerFooterPart, OpenXmlPart customP, Picture pic)
{
    Bitmap image = new Bitmap(customP.GetStream());

    ...omitted - fails on this line
}
```

`RunCode`

```
<w:p w:rsidR="00624DF2" w:rsidRDefault="009E3005" xmlns:w="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main">
  <w:pPr>
    <w:pStyle w:val="OfficeAddress" />
    <w:rPr>
      <w:sz w:val="10" />
    </w:rPr>
  </w:pPr>
  <w:r>
    <w:pict>
      <v:shapetype id="_x0000_t75" coordsize="21600,21600" filled="f" stroked="f" o:spt="75" o:preferrelative="t" path="m@4@5l@4@11@9@11@9@5xe" xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml">
        <v:stroke joinstyle="miter" />
        <v:formulas>
          <v:f eqn="if lineDrawn pixelLineWidth 0" />
          <v:f eqn="sum @0 1 0" />
          <v:f eqn="sum 0 0 @1" />
          <v:f eqn="prod @2 1 2" />
          <v:f eqn="prod @3 21600 pixelWidth" />
          <v:f eqn="prod @3 21600 pixelHeight" />
          <v:f eqn="sum @0 0 1" />
          <v:f eqn="prod @6 1 2" />
          <v:f eqn="prod @7 21600 pixelWidth" />
          <v:f eqn="sum @8 21600 0" />
          <v:f eqn="prod @7 21600 pixelHeight" />
          <v:f eqn="sum @10 21600 0" />
        </v:formulas>
        <v:path gradientshapeok="t" o:connecttype="rect" o:extrusionok="f" />
        <o:lock v:ext="edit" aspectratio="t" />
      </v:shapetype>
      <v:shape id="_x0000_s2049" style="position:absolute;left:0;text-align:left;margin-left:395.25pt;margin-top:3.6pt;width:87pt;height:50.45pt;z-index:251657728" type="#_x0000_t75" xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml">
        <v:imagedata o:title="" r:id="rId1" xmlns:r="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships" xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" />
      </v:shape>
    </w:pict>
  </w:r>
</w:p>
```

`Document.xml.rels - ommited for brevity`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Relationships xmlns="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/package/2006/relationships">
  <Relationship Id="rId1" Type="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships/customXml" Target="../customXml/item1.xml" />
</Relationships>
```

`CustomXml/item.xml`

```
<b:Sources SelectedStyle="\APASixthEditionOfficeOnline.xsl" StyleName="APA" Version="6" xmlns:b="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/bibliography" xmlns="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/bibliography"></b:Sources>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
using (WordprocessingDocument doc = WordprocessingDocument.Open("document.docx", false)){ 
    var imageParts = doc.MainDocumentPart.ImageParts; 
    foreach(var imagePart in imageParts) { 
        var imageStream = imagePart.GetStream(); 
        //Do somtehing with the stream here. 
        Image bmp = new Bitmap(imageStream);
    } 
}
```

Once you have the image stream data, its just a matter of converting that into a Bitmap object and placing it inside the Run where you want it copied.

I haven't executed this code but, this should work.
Check this [link](http://openxmldeveloper.org/discussions/formats/f/13/p/5028/157775.aspx) out as well.

Comment: I'll give this a go - not sure if it contains an ImagePart though :/

Comment: I'd highly recommend you use the [Open XML SDK 2.5 Productivity tool](http://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=30425). Also, if you have a picture/image in the word document, there should be an image part, use the tool to check.

Comment: I did use the tool - that's how I got the XML as in my question. Thx